# Sampling with replacement or sampling without replacement?

Tags: probability

> A psychology class consists of $14$ males and $36$ females. If a
> random sample of $n=3$ students is selected and the first two are both
> females, what is the probability that the third student selected will
> be a male?

This is a problem from a text book I have been studying from. There was a similar problem about a jar containing $10$ red marbles and $30$ blue marbles, and when asked that if we were to take a random sample of $n=3$ marbles from the jar and the first two marbles are both blue, what is the probability that the third marble will be red? The answer was $\dfrac{10}{40}$ because as mentioned in the book that random sampling requires sampling with replacement.

However, this does not seem to apply to the question about the psychology class, because the answer to that question was $\dfrac{14}{48}$. When the two females were chosen, we did not apply what we have done when we were talking about marbles, because we subtracted $2$ from the total number of students.

How can I differentiate when it is sampling with replacement or sampling without replacement?

Comment: Marble question is ambiguous.  After each marble is selected, is it returned?  Student question is definitely without replacement.